# Using razor to set javascript variables inline, is it good practice/safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

If I wanted to set some javascript variables from my model would that be a safe practice?  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVariable = '@Model.myVar';
</script>
```

Is this an ok practice?  I cant think of a better way to really do it, besides maybe doing hidden input, but that seems like too much work compared to this.  I just dont know if this is vulnerable or if there's something im overlooking by doing this.

Comment: It's better practice to use a hidden input and then you can decouple your JavaScript from your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues with this. Fundamentally, you are tightly coupling your javascript to your page or view. I would consider myself a solid .NET / C# / MVC developer but a beginner with javascript and this is exactly the type of design that I pursued up until recently. In the past I would in-lining all kinds of javascript within my views and making heavy use of Razor. In the end it works but it leads to a very tight coupling of your markup and script and ultimately produces a difficult environment to maintain.

A much better approach would be to instead in-line calls to javascript functions. The difference is subtle but it will enforce the separation of these two areas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyFunction('@Model.myVar');
</script>
```

You can also in-line values in hidden input fields, spans etc via Razor and expose them there to your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe as the output is encoded by default in razor.

However if the value you are outputting is a value the user can change, you'd have to make sure it was validated (Server side) to stop any XSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're fine doing that. There won't be any vulnerabilities introduced by doing this. Doesn't stop vulnerabilities from coming through if they were already there, but this certainly won't add any more.